# How OpenCV convert image to grayscale?

Tags: opencv, grayscale

I converted an image to grayscale, and then I wondered that was going on inside. I found 2 ways how it could be, but what is really going on inside?
2 ways:

> Average the channels

This method involves taking the arithmetic average of the pixel values.

> Сhannel-dependent luminance perception

It is more biological way. It involves the use of

> 0.2126 * R-value + 0.7152 * G-value + 0.0752 * B-value.

The method is based on the presence of cones in people`s eyes.

Source: [www.kdnuggets.com](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/12/convert-rgb-image-grayscale.html#:%7E:text=An%20intuitive%20way%20to%20convert,into%20a%20reasonable%20gray%20approximation.).

But what is the OpenCV using for grayscale?

Comment: Have a look at the docs: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ITU-R standards that define color conversions.
OpenCV uses BT.709 and your formula is BT.601. For more check here
https://mymusing.co/bt601-yuv-to-rgb-conversion-color/

Answer (score 1):

> RGB[A] to Gray:Y←0.299⋅R+0.587⋅G+0.114⋅B

Source: [docs.opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html).